# Working with Beaker Cache and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, caching, sqlalchemy, beaker

I'm trying to use beaker cache with SQLAlchemy but I've been receiving errors.

Here are my table definitions.

```
class Post(Base):
  ....
  ....

  user = relation(User, primaryjoin = User.id == id)
  tags = relation('Tags', backref = 'posts')


class Tags(Base):
  ...
  ...

  user = relation(User, primaryjoin = User.id == id)
  post = relation(Post, primaryjoin = Post.id == id)
```

beaker cache works with other SQLAlchemy classes except these ones.

When I run the program, I receive the following error;

```
DetachedInstanceError: Parent instance <Post at 0x101f90b10> is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of attribute 'user' cannot proceed.
```

I've searched on StackOverFlow and have found in another thread that I need to disable lazy loading so I've changed the line

```
user = relation(User, primaryjoin = User.id == id)
```

to

```
user = relation(User, primaryjoin = User.id == id, lazy='dynamic')
```

but this occurs to following error in template(`post.user.fullname`);

```
AttributeError: 'AppenderQuery' object has no attribute 'fullname'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you grab objects from cache, you should associate them with a session object, eg.

```
obj_from_cache = get_from_cache(key)
session.merge(obj_from_cache)
```